# Redirect all pages of a domain using htaccess to a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is a wordpress website (I'm not sure it does change anything),

At the moment domain.info goes to domain.com as expected,
But domain.info/page-1/ is displaying instead of being redirected to domain.com.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Shail but it doesn't work, it says "The page isn't redirecting properly"